# What is the etymology of the word teeter totter?

Tags: etymology, transatlantic-differences

Seesaw and teeter totter are two names for the same piece of playground equipment.  I grew up using the word teeter totter mostly, but was aware of seesaw, as it was used in books.

I was wondering whether it is a regional difference or a generational difference.

From [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/teeter-totter), I found that there are even more terms used for this equipment: *tilt* or a *tilting board*,  *teedle board*,  *dandle* or *dandle board*. *Teeter* or *teeterboard*, and  *teeter-totter*, which is probably the most common term after *seesaw*.  So it is indeed a regional term,
which also explains why Google Ngrams has no recorded use of teeter totter in British English:
[Link to Ngram for seesaw teeter totter in British English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=teeter%20totter,seesaw&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3)

Yet, if seesaw was in use since before 1800, how and why did teeter totter come into use seemingly all of a sudden just before 1920?
[Link to Ngram for seesaw teeter totter in American English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seesaw,%20teeter%20totter&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3)

[Link to Online Etymology Dictionary for seesaw](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=seesaw&searchmode=none)

Comment: Ngrams and [sometimes-hyphenated-words](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2Csee+-+saw%2C+seesaw%2Cteeter+-+totter%2Cteeter+totter%2C+teetertotter&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) can be notoriously tricky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to your question is that it is a regional not a generational difference.

*Teeter-totter* is the most widespread in America.  *Seesaw* is specifically Southern.  *Dandle* is from Rhode Island.  Other regional variants include  *dandle board, teedle board, teeter, teeterboard, tilt,* and *tilting board.* See the [*Dictionary of American Regional English*](http://dare.wisc.edu/) for details.

Etymologically, the word *teeter-totter* was formed by reduplication of either *titter* or *totter*.  It derives from *titter*, now a dialect form for *teeter*, and *totter*, which means the same thing. The OED also attests *titter-totter*, and says to see the *Engl. Dial. Dict.* for details.  The earliest citation is:

> - 1607 R. C[arew] tr. *Estienne’s World of Wonders* 266 
>    He played with a little boy at titter-totter.

*See-saw* is also a reduplicative word, and its earliest citations are also from the 1600s, although a bit later than the previous one.  However, those are all just interjections. The first noun use is this one:

> - 1704 *Swift Mechan. Operat. Spirit Misc.* 297 
>    Then, as they sit, they are in a perpetual Motion of See-saw.

And the first verb citation is this:

> - 1712 Arbuthnot *John Bull* ɪᴠ. vii, 
>    So they went see-sawing up and down, from one End of the Room to the other.

Comment: Please link the dictionary reverenced and take a look here:  http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seesaw%2Cteeter+totter&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3

Comment: @SpareOom Done.  Also, [see this question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/should-we-allow-google-ngrams-to-be-presented-as-statistical-evidence-without-qu) regarding Google N-grams, which of course have nothing to do with speech.

Comment: Great link on use of N-grams.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Seesaw is southern? I'm from PA and I always called it a seesaw. It could be a local thing too...

Comment: For what it's worth, I grew up on Long Island, New York, and we always called it a seesaw. It wasn't until I moved to Ohio that I heard it called a teeter-totter.

Comment: Seesaw is the only term used in England.

Comment: @SpareOom: "Teeter-totter" is not as rare as your Ngram suggests – you left out the hyphen.  Check out [this one](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seesaw%2Cteeter+-+totter&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3).

Comment: @J.R. Thanks. I had tried it with a hyphen, but not the right way, apparently, which I found out from tchrist's link.  I have much to learn.  Also, thanks for the edit.